# Text on a picture, when the picture is centered

Tags: html, css

Here you can see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WdZeC/

```
<div class="text_align_center" style="text-align: center;">
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <img width="27" height="28" src="http://www.kavoir.com/img/text-over-image.jpg">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width:27px; background-color: red;">1</div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <img width="27" height="28" src="http://www.kavoir.com/img/text-over-image.jpg">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width:27px; background-color: red;">1</div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <img width="27" height="28" src="http://www.kavoir.com/img/text-over-image.jpg">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width:27px; background-color: red;">1</div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <img width="27" height="28" src="http://www.kavoir.com/img/text-over-image.jpg">
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width:27px; background-color: red;">1</div>
    </div>

<img width="27" height="28" src="http://www.kavoir.com/img/text-over-image.jpg"><img width="27" height="28" src="http://www.kavoir.com/img/text-over-image.jpg"><img width="27" height="28" src="http://www.kavoir.com/img/text-over-image.jpg"><img width="27" height="28" src="http://www.kavoir.com/img/text-over-image.jpg"><img width="27" height="28" src="http://www.kavoir.com/img/text-over-image.jpg"><img width="27" height="28" src="http://www.kavoir.com/img/text-over-image.jpg"><div class="left">
</div>
```

I want to do the following:

```
 IMG IMG IMG IMG IMG IMG IMG
```

and writing onto the img, preferably at the center of them. Everything is text-align: center; but it looks the text is still assigned to left

Comment: set the images as background of the text. set width for text and add float

Comment: sadly it must be "clickable"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: http://jsfiddle.net/WdZeC/1/

```
<div class="container" >
    <div class="text_align_center">
        <img width="27" height="28" class="img_under" src="http://www.kavoir.com/img/text-over-image.jpg" />
        <div class="over_img">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="text_align_center">
        <img width="27" height="28" class="img_under" src="http://www.kavoir.com/img/text-over-image.jpg" />
       <div class="over_img">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="text_align_center">
        <img width="27" height="28" class="img_under" src="http://www.kavoir.com/img/text-over-image.jpg" />
        <div class="over_img">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="text_align_center">
        <img width="27" height="28" class="img_under" src="http://www.kavoir.com/img/text-over-image.jpg" />
        <div class="over_img">1</div>
    </div>
</div>



.text_align_center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 27px; height: 28px;
}
.img_under {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
.over_img {
    width: 27px; height: 28px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

Comment: one thing, they need to be next to each other :)

Answer (score 3):

Outer container needs to be set to relative and text aligned center and the inner text needs to be set to absolute with a width.

http://cdpn.io/spqlF

And the Chris Coyier post on this topic - http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/